# Undefined method `+@' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError) ruby

Tags: ruby, undefined

```
def next_prime_number (last_known_prime)
  while true
    last_known_prime++

    found_factor = false # ERROR
    for i in 1...last_known_prime
      if last_known_prime % i == 0
        found_factor = true
        break
      end
    end
    if !found_factor
      puts "new prime: #{last_known_prime}"
      Kernel.exit
    end
  end
end

in `next_prime_number': undefined method `+@' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

I'm getting the above error and am totally stumped. Any ideas (no, this is not homework, I am trying to teach myself Ruby through the Euler Project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mikej said, there is no post-increment (`++`) operator in ruby. There is however, a unary plus (spelled `+@` when defining it)

```
last_known_prime++

found_factor = false
```

is getting parsed as something like

```
last_known_prime + (+(found_factor = false))

--------------------^ unary plus on false
```

which is causing your cryptic error.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `++` operator for incrementing an integer in Ruby so try replacing `last_known_prime++` with `last_known_prime = last_known_prime + 1`.

This will fix the error you're seeing. There is another problem with your program after that but I won't spoil your attempt to solve the Euler problem yourself.

Comment: Or last_known_prime += 1 or last_known_prime = last_known_prime.succ

Comment: Thanks @Logan, I had a feeling there was a method like `.succ` but I couldn't remember its name off the top of my head.