# NoMethodError undefined method '-@' NoMethodError in Controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nomethoderror, unary-operator

**Context:**
I pulled the most recent code from the repository and tried to make sure that the changes I was about to push up were going to work with that version of the code.  This is a Ruby on Rails application.  Also worth noting is the fact that when running the main application that I pulled from on the web, this error does not show up.  But if I run my branch or the main branch cloned onto my environment, the error always shows up for every url I try.  So it is on my end.

**Problem:**
As soon as I go to localhost:3000, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in HomeController#index
undefined method `-@' for #<ActionDispatch::Response:0x64fd460>
```

**What I've Tried:**
I have asked my question on the *#rubyonrails* IRC channel and nobody was able to determine what was going on through the Full Trace (I haven't posted it here because I wasn't sure what was the best way to do that on here; it didn't look very good in the code block or block quote).  I have looked at my HomeController's index method, which is defined as such:

```
    def index
      @groups = @current_user.groups
      @things = Thing.where(:group_id => @groups.map{|e|e.id})
    end
```

I have also Googled around and haven't found what I need to fix the problem.

**What I've Learned So Far:**
-@ is an operator.  Some people may receive a similar error in assuming that Ruby has the shortcut to

```
    variable = variable + 1
```

that a lot of other languages have:

```
    variable++
```

Here is an example of that case: [Undefined method `+@' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError) ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3548701/1480946)

**Question:**
Does anyone have any further suggestions on how to find the issue here?  Also, if I could easily put the Full Trace on here, formatted in an aesthetically pleasing manner, would someone tell me how?  I'm at a loss with this one :(

**Update (2/8/2013):**
It seems that the issue does not necessarily reside in the HomeController nor home/index.html.erb View.  I have attempted to access ANY url with a valid action and the same error occurs with "NoMethodError in..." changing to the corresponding [...]Controller#index.

**Update (2/9/2013):**
Since this error happens no matter what url I try to navigate to, I decided to look in the routes.rb file in the config folder.  I ran my server through rubymine instead of the command line this time, which made it a little easier to read for me.  I started looking through all the spit out and I noticed an interested line that consisted of:

```
["private-key looking thing"] [127.0.0.1] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-09 18:20:52 -0700
```

It seems like there is a syntactical error in routes.rb (that's my best guess at this point).  This does not explain why this only is an issue on my local environment with the same code sets, but what else do I have to go off of?

Does anyone have any suggested things to be on the look out for while I sift through this file?  Not really sure what to be looking for as far as errors are concerned.  Rubymines inspection stuff converted all my double quotes to single quotes and doesn't really have anything else to complain about.

Thanks in advance,
Jake Smith

Comment: can you show where you are finding @current_user ?

Comment: The `-@` method corresponds to the unary negation operator, similarly for `!@`, `+@`, etc. So apparently someone is saying `-thing` where `thing` is an `ActionDispatch::Response`.

Comment: vijikumar: I am still pretty new at how things work in the ruby on rails world.  Can you elaborate on your question?  Do you mean where @current_user is ultimately defined?

Comment: Jake: going off the very helpful response from @muistooshort, you should search your application for any code with `- thing` in it. If this is happening on every route in your app, that means the offending code has to also be executed on every request, so it's in application controller or an initializer, or some model that you're using everywhere... something like that. Try that search and see what you find.

Comment: Another tip: make small, incremental commits, testing continuously, and then when you hit a mysterious bug like this you can go back to the last commit and re-implement your changes bit by bit until the error reappears. Sometimes that's the best way to track really rare bugs down.

Comment: Andrew: Thanks for the tips!  I've done a search on -@ and other variations and I couldn't find any.  I think that's because there actually are probably some sort of character or a few between the two characters in question here.  If you look at my first update, this doesn't just pertain the Things.  This error will appear no matter what url I try to navigate to.  So this is a really hard one to do a find-all for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue!

### What fixed it:

1. Go to the directory where your gems are (for me that was C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1)
2. Delete all gems except for bundler
3. Make sure you delete the gems from the /cache/, /gems/, and /specifications/ folders (I just deleted them from the /gems/ folder at first and `bundle install` indicated that it could still find the gems)
4. Run `bundle install`

### Further Inquiry:

Does anybody have any idea why this worked?  I don't know if at this point I can narrow down which gem was causing the issue because the app is working now (I can visit all the urls with corresponding views).  If the issue comes up again, I will delete gems one by one to nail down which one was at least causing the issue for me.  But if anyone has any insight on this, a more detailed answer would be greatly appreciated by many more people than just me, I think.  Thanks to all who helped thus far!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it might as well be an syntactical error in the corresponding view page Home/index.html.haml .. I am suspecting there is unintended '-' in front of variable call. I tried to simulate a similar scenario in my rails platform and see following page on browser

```
undefined method `-@' for false:FalseClass
```

Correct lines of code

```
%h1 All Movies
= "filtervalue=#{@isFilterOld}"
= "Sortvalue=#{@isSortOld}"
```

Edited to simulate the error (observe the - in front of isFilterOld variable)

```
   %h1 All Movies
    = "filtervalue=#{-@isFilterOld}"
    = "Sortvalue=#{@isSortOld}"
```

Comment: prashantsunkari: Thank you for your suggestion, that seems to be a similar reason why you would get "undefined method '+@'" as an error as I mentioned above.  There must be a "-" in front of a variable definition or use like you are suggesting.  As soon as I am able to verify this, I will post my results.  Thanks again!

Comment: prashantsunkari: I was unable to find any issue in app/views/home/index.html.erb.  I wonder what else it could be?

Comment: sorry for the late comment.. I am not sure what might have caused it other then my input above here...  glad that you figured out the fix, as I see below!